# AVplayer Step by count stuttering when used with -ve value

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, avplayer

In my app i have to play video forward and backward on swipe, and i am using AVPlayer step by count for that. It is working fine when used forward but stuttering when used backwards. I also enabled `canPlayReverse` & `canStepBackward`for AVPlayerItem but the result is the same. Although,I searched for answers regarding this,but couldn't find any definite solution to this. How can i make it work backwards?

Answer (score 1):

Actually , i solved  my own problem.
Use this code:

```
avPlayer.rate=1.0;

avPlayer.rate=-1.0;
```

The 1.0 rate is for forward playing of video whereas -1.0 is for reverse playing. it is a lot more smoother now compared to the output i was getting earlier.